# Unexpected UTC offsets of fractions of an hour using PYTZ with common timezones

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I am having trouble understanding the effect of timezone offsets using `pytz`.

I start with a time in UTC, like this:

```
>>> utc = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 5, 7, 59, 58, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("UTC"))
```

Now I take the same wall clock time in EST, which is 5 standard meridians to the west and should differ (I believe) by 5 hours.

```
>>> est = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 5, 7, 59, 58, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("US/Eastern"))
>>> est-utc
datetime.timedelta(seconds=17760)
>>> 17760/3600
4.933333333333334
```

That difference is not the 5 hours I expect, but 4h56m, short by 4 minutes

Continuing to the west I try to arrive at times with one hour successively earlier:

```
>>> cst = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 5, 7, 59, 58, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("US/Central"))
>>> cst-utc
datetime.timedelta(seconds=21060)
>>> 21060/3600
5.85
```

That difference is not the expected 6 hours, but 5h51, short by 9 minutes.

```
>>> mst = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 5, 7, 59, 58, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("US/Mountain"))
>>> mst-utc
datetime.timedelta(seconds=25200)
>>> 25200/3600
7.0
```

This yields the expected 7-hour difference.

```
>>> pst = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 5, 7, 59, 58, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("US/Pacific"))
>>> pst-utc
datetime.timedelta(seconds=28380)
>>> 28380/3600
7.883333333333334
```

Now the difference is not the expected 8 hours but 7h53, short by 7 minutes.

And if I display the times, this is what I get:

```
>>> est
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 5, 7, 59, 58, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)
>>> cst
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 5, 7, 59, 58, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Central' LMT-1 day, 18:09:00 STD>)
>>> mst
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 5, 7, 59, 58, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Mountain' LMT-1 day, 17:00:00 STD>)
>>> pst
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 5, 7, 59, 58, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' LMT-1 day, 16:07:00 STD>)
```

So `datetime` is fully aware that the UTC offsets of these times vary from the expected even number of hours by respectively 4, 9, 0 and 7 minutes.

Clearly my expectations of how these timezone offsets should work is not correct.

I tried again with simpler timezone names: `pytz` recognizes EST and CST, and yields the expected whole-hour offsets for them, but rejects MST and PST.

Now, I obtained these results on Windows 10, and I can already hear an answer along the lines of "Ah, well, *Windows*, everybody knows that timezones on Windows are bizarre" (which is true), but they are not *that* bizarre, and besides, I get results identical to the ones shown above from Python 3.8 on Linux.

What am I missing here?

Comment: see also [pytz: The Fastest Footgun in the West](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the simplest solution is not to try and understand what `pytz.tzinfo` is doing, but instead move to `zoneinfo.ZoneInfo` that was added to the standard library in Python 3.9.